# $.ajax & $.post working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I've tried both $.ajax & $.post and both are not working in Safari or Firefox. Oddly enough, they are working in Chrome. The 'savemarkup.php' call works fine but the 'sendemail.php' is throwing an error (which comes back to my console as an object). The 'sendemail.php' utilizes PhpMailer to send an email based on selections made in the program.

```
function generatePDF () {
$("#saving").css("display","none");
var email = generateEmail();
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
$.post (
'savemarkup.php', {
    markup: markup,
    email: email
},
function (data,status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        $("#saving").fadeIn("fast");
        //$.post('sendemail.php');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sendemail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(res) { 
                console.log( res ); 
            }, 
            error: function (xhr) { 
                console.log( xhr ); 
            }
        });
        var saveDelay = 1000;
        if (i > 3) {
            saveDelay = 333 * i;
        }
        $("#saving-image").attr("src","http://quote.hekmancontract.com/images/please-wait-pdf.gif");
        window.location = 'savepdf.php';
        $("#saving").delay(saveDelay).fadeOut("fast");
        $("#saving-image").attr("src","http://quote.hekmancontract.com/images/please-wait-saving.gif");
    }
});
}
```

I can't copy and paste the error log very easily so I've included a snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Your snapshot is showing a regular XHR object, not the actual error?

Comment: Try `error: function (xhr, status err) { console.log(status); console.log(err); }` to look at the actual error?

Comment: My guess is that the AJAX request gets aborted, since you're navigating away (`window.location = ...`) before waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Interesting thought but why would it work in Chrome then? I'm asking, not challenging just FYI. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: error: function (xhr, status, err) { console.log(status); console.log(err); } just logs 'error'. I also had to add a comma after the status variable.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the typo. It should log two things. Which one is `'error'`?

Comment: Could network speed effect this? My office is slow (T1) but as soon as I got home it worked like a charm. It is also working after I moved the window.location in the success function.

Comment: Yeah, it could just be a race as to which thing finishes first (the AJAX call or the navigation).